# Disabling built in screen color post-processing on Android devices

Tags: android, settings

It seems some Android devices manufacturers trick their users by applying a very agressive post process on the screen to make them look more vibrant. One example would be the Samsung Galaxy S2 which has it's default saturation mode so outrageously overdone that it's almost laughable.

It's a nice screen, don't get me wrong, but now my nice war game looks like a clown festival. I tried applying a post process countering the hardware one but it's:

- Way too slow
- Some devices have a user option to change them from one outrageous color mode to the other (such as the S2).

**Is there a way to temporarily change those settings from my app?** Or at the very least, is there a way to know what screen mode is currently active so that I can compensate appropriately without asking the user to change his screen mode to a specific setting?